# Typeface.BOLD & Typeface.ITALIC is not working properly with Custom Typeface

Tags: android, android-typeface

I'm making a text editor and there are two buttons, one for **Bold** and second for **Italic**. I've written following code...

```
private void setBoldListener() {
    btnBold.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (editText.getTypeface() != null) {
                if (editText.getTypeface().isBold()) {
                    if (editText.getTypeface().isItalic()) {
                        editText.setTypeface(editText.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);
                    } else {
                        editText.setTypeface(editText.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (editText.getTypeface().isItalic()) {
                        editText.setTypeface(editText.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                    } else {
                        editText.setTypeface(editText.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void setItalicListener() {
    btnItalic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (editText.getTypeface() != null) {
                if (editText.getTypeface().isItalic()) {
                    if (editText.getTypeface().isBold()) {
                        editText.setTypeface(editText.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    } else {
                        editText.setTypeface(editText.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (editText.getTypeface().isBold()) {
                        editText.setTypeface(editText.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                    } else {
                        editText.setTypeface(editText.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The code is working fine when my EditText has default font, I mean default typeface. But if I change the typeface (font) using

```
editText.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Comic Sans MS.ttf"));
```

the code is not working properly. I tried many solutions but got failure each time. Please suggest me what am I missing?

Comment: Wild guess: You did not provide the bold (`comicbd.ttf`) and italic (`comici.ttf`) ttf files.

Comment: No..! Because android system is managing bold/italic automatically. But I'm getting a strange behavior. If text is bold then italic will work, or text is italic then bold will work, and we cant remove bold/italic again while clicking on these buttons again.

Comment: Comic Sans comes split into **4** ttf files: regular, bold, italic and bold + italic. Simply add the missing files to your assets folder

Comment: Comic sans is just for an example, I'm using many fonts.

Comment: Each font comes split into several variants. You really need to provide ALL the variants you're going to use.